# Using JQuery, is it possible to build a drag/drop object that can be instantiated multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, dom

Good day!

I have a page with a vertical menu off to the left and a  box to the right of it.  Currently I am able to drag a ghost of a menu item and let go of it. It doesn't actually drop anything, so there is no actual change to the menu. When I drop the ghost, it calls a method.

What I'd like to be able to do is to create an object with JQuery or plain javascript or whatever and instantiate it.

This object would have the following properties:
-  Have its parent be the div box that its dropped on.
-  Be contained by its parent, yet draggable within it.
-  Have the ability to be a parent of another object of the same type when its dragged into it from the menu
-  Have a title based on the menu item that it was dragged from
-  Store whatever text values are assigned to it.

I'm not asking anyone to do this (although you can if you want), but I would love to know if its possible and if anyone can provide a link to some sample of an object or widget being built that can be assigned properties and events.

Thanks so much,
Carlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that will work for me.  Instead of reinventing the wheel, I will just modify the Jquery-UI's dialog widget.  its alomst exactly what I need out of the box.  There's an interesting article on it here:  http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/tips-for-developing-jquery-ui-widgets/

Thanks much for the help, all.

Answer (score 1):

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

This is really by far your best option. I have seen others, but this does exactly what your are describing. Most of the time sortable does everything you want, but if it gets really complicated, say you want to have the item your currently on light up or not be easily contained in an option you can still use draggable and droppable to do w/e you want.

Comment: Thanks but sortable is the functionality that I already have on my menu off to the left.  What I really need to do is to be able to instantiate an object... a div box with values in it... that can be dropped into a parent div box and also become a parent div box on its own

Comment: I have done this many times with jquery ui. You will prbably need to use draggable and droppable and write the custom rules on when an object is considered draggable and dropable. sortable is only used for simple cases.